# Send JSON object as post request and deserialize to a web DTO object - how to get Polymorphic model binding work in web api for data validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, dto

I have control over what data outside server sends to this API endpoint, and I built an API controller for the endpoint. The problem is the endpoint will receive the JSON object from the request body and deserialize it to a web DTO object. Here I want the API controller to perform data validation based on the Data Annotations in Web DTO forms. The API endpoint converts JSON object to web DTO object, and it then passes the data to another function in API controller (below). I wanted used the following code to achieve this purpose but it seems that ModelState.IsValid always returns true:

```
        public StatusMessage ValidateDto(ModelDto dataDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new StatusMessage("Unable to validate");
            }
            
            return new StatusMessage("success");

        }
```

I have ModelBinders under App_Start to determine which models the data is binding, however ModelState.IsValid always return true even if the JSON object contains data exceeding "Range". Has anyone dealt with similar situations before?